# Как перевести Си-шный код в Ассемблер-овский?

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Доброго времени суток. Какой программой можно перевести этот Си-шный код в Ассемблеровский? Что можете посоветовать? Я по ассемблеру нуб. Вот Сишный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int results[10];
unsigned int trub ()
{
  int loop;
  for(loop=0;loop<10;loop++)
  {
    if (loop == 0)  results[loop]=0;
    if (loop == 1)  results[loop]=0;
    if (loop == 2)  results[loop]=1;
    if (loop>2)  results[loop]=results[loop - 1] + results[loop - 2]+results[loop - 3];
  }

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  trub();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте

```
gcc -S
```